# Sorting a String based on its words

Tags: java, strings, sorting

Is there a better, more efficient or nicer way to do this?

```
public static String sortString(String s){

    String[] strArray= s.split("\\s+");
    Arrays.sort(strArray);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<strArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(strArray[i]);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of comments:

- `String[] strArray = s.split("\\s+");` will create a `Pattern` object each time this is called, which might hurt the performance. It would be better to reuse the same pattern. Declare it as a constant:

  ```
  private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
  ```

  and then you can use

  ```
  String[] strArray = PATTERN.split(s);
  ```
- Use a for-each loop instead of a loop using index. This is both easier to read and to maintain when you don't need the index. So instead of having

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<strArray.length; i++){
      sb.append(strArray[i]);
  ```

  you can have

  ```
  for (String str : strArray){
      sb.append(str);
  ```

---

If you can use Java 8, you could have

```
public static String sortString(String s){
    return PATTERN.splitAsStream(s).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

This splits the input String into a `Stream<String>` using [`splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-). Then the stream is sorted and finally collected with a collector joining all elements together, separated by a space, using [`Collectors.joining(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-). As a side-note, this will not include the last white-space at the end of the joined Strings, unlike the code in your question.

Answer (score 4):

You could pass the length of the source string to the `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
```

That way, you make sure that the builder does not have to resize in order to accommodate the string, and that you don't waste memory.

Also, I would fix a little bit (taking the advice by [vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp)):

```
sb.append(strArray[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < strArray.length; ++i) {
    sb.append(" ").append(strArray[i]);
}
```

..., so that you do not conclude the last word with a space.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Testing for such condition at each iteration hurts performance. Recommended way is to `sb.append(strArray[0]); for (i = 1; i < strArray.length; ++i) { sb.append(" "); sb.append(strArray[i]); }`

Comment: True. Is it ok to edit my answer on behalf of this issue?

Comment: @coderodde yes it's ok to improve (even rewrite) your answer based on comments you receive. When doing so, it's recommended to credit vnp for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Here's one which removes the entirety of the `StringBuilder` operations you do. If on Java 8, simply use `String.join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements)`. In your case, `delimiter` would be `" "`, and `elements` would be `strArray`.

Final Code:

```
public static String sortString(String s){
    String[] strArray = s.split("\\s+");
    Arrays.sort(strArray);
    return String.join(" ", strArray);
}
```

(A Java 8 3-liner solution, possibly a bit less complex than the one proposed by @Tunaki - 3 method calls here to 4 there).

And, since we are on Java 8 already, and you are concerned about performance and have really long 40-50 word `String`s, try `Arrays.parallelSort(Object[])` in place of `Arrays.sort(Object[])`.